Почему Open AI GPT может на запускаться на сервере, который расположен в Германии
При попытке запросов выводится сообщение:
openai.PermissionDeniedError: Error code: 403 - {'error': {'code': 'unsupported_country_region_territory', 'message': '**Country, region, or territory not supported**', 'param': None, 'type': 'request_forbidden'}}

Код запускаю на сервере с локацией в Германии.
Тот же код работает с ПК через VPN. Что можно проверить?
